# Map the entity with embedded List from one view

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, cqrs

I m trying to implement the simple cqrs application using spring-data-jpa
So I have 2 tables used to write - for instance person & car (one person can have list of cars). 
I use also the one view created as a select * from person join car...

So the sample query from can give the output (one user has 2 cars)

```
firstName|lastName| car_brand | car_model |
marek    |k       | tesla     | s         |
marek    |k       | mercdes   | 190       |
```

Now I m trying to map this view in jpa and I m trying to embedded list

```
@Embeddable
class CarSnapshot {
   private String carBrand;
   private String carModel;
}
```

and

```
class PersonSnapshot {
   private String firstName;
   @Embedded // I tried also @OneToMany and ElementCollection
   private Set<CarSnapshot> cars;
}
```

But it does not work in my case. Do You have any idea how to fix it
moreover the one-to-one mapping (person has max one car) works pretty cool

Comment: Why do you use `@Embedded`? Just testing? What is the problem with `@OneToMany`?

Comment: @pirho You don't use `@OneToMany` on an embedded collection

Comment: @BillyFrost Yes, but I was just curious why using embedded collection instead of an entity & `@OneToMany` because of this comment:  _I tried also `@OneToMany`_.

Comment: Because I ve no dedicated table for car_snapshot . It s part of the view.
I receive the 'Use of OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class'

Comment: @marek.kapowicki Ok, I see it now from `cqrs` point of view. I kind a missed the _Snapshot_ part. I am not 100% sure but I think you could be able to do this also with _projection_. Just think that you need to be able to persist these snapshots also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use embeddable type you can do the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_cars", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"), foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "person_cars_persons_fk"))
    private List<PersonCar> cars;
}

@Embeddable
class PersonCar {

   @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
   private String brand;

   @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
   private String model;
}
```

In this case your db schema can be like this:

```
create table persons (
  id integer not null constraint persons_pkey primary key,
);

create table person_cars (
  person_id integer not null constraint person_cars_persons_fk references persons,

  brand varchar(32) not null,
  model varchar(32) not null,

  constraint supported_docs_pkey primary key (doc_type, country_code)
);
```

(It's postgresql dialect)

More info is here: [Hibernate User Guide - Collections of value types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-value)

**UPDATED**

To map a View to the entity you can do like this:

```
@Data // It's Lombok annotation - c-tor, getters/setters etc.
@Entity
@Immutable
@IdClass(View.class)
@Subselect("select p.name as person_name, c.brand as car_brand, c.model as car_model from persons p join cars c on p.id = c.person_id")
public class View implements Serializable {

    @Id private String personName;
    @Id private String carBrand;
    @Id private String carModel;
}
```

Instead of using `@Subselect` annotation you can use `@Table` annotation with name of your View:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Immutable
@IdClass(View.class)
@Table(name = "my_view")
public class View implements Serializable {...}
```

Working [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/view-demo).

**UPDATED 2**

Workaround with post-processing...

DTOs:

```
@Value
public class PersonDto {
    private String name;
    private List<CarDto> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    public PersonDto addCars(List<CarDto> cars) {
        this.cars.addAll(cars);
        return this;
    }
}

@Value
public class CarDto {
    private String brand;
    private String model;
}
```

And `ViewRepo`

```
public interface ViewRepo extends JpaRepository<View, View> {

    List<View> findByPersonName(String name);

    default PersonDto getPersonByName(String personName) {
        return new PersonDto(personName)
                .addCars(findByPersonName(personName)
                        .stream()
                        .map(p -> new CarDto(p.getCarBrand(), p.getCarModel()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this article, but it is not my case
I have the one view (not 2 tables) and I m trying to map the view to the model, without changing the db...

Comment: I can see - but in this case as I understand You mapped each record of view to instance of View class. So as a result of my example You received 2 View objects

My goal is to map it to single person  object with List of 2 entities...

I thought that it is easy to achieve in jpa...but so far i could not do it

Comment: @marek.kapowicki you cannot map a flat view to the hierarchal entity. You can do you need only if you map two associated entities (or entity and embeddable class) to related tables.